# AWS Kinesis data stream Scala read from Spark error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-kinesis

I'm using the following code to establish a data stream, but when I submit the code I get NoSuchMethodError for KinesisUtils.

```
// AWS KINESIS
val endPoint = "https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
val streamName = "PRICESIZE_REALTIME_STAGING"
val credentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials()
require(credentials != null, "No AWS credentials found")
val kinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient(credentials)
kinesisClient.setEndpoint(endPoint)
val numShards = kinesisClient.describeStream(streamName).getStreamDescription().getShards().size

// STREAM`
val kinesisStream = KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc, appName, streamName,
  endPoint, Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).toString,
  InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, Duration(frequesncyMilli), StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)

// Convert each line of Array[Byte] to String, and split into words
 val words = kinesisStream.flatMap(byteArray => new String(byteArray, "UTF-8").split(" "))
```

I am building with as: mvn -Pkinesis-asl -DskipTests clean package.

Submitting produces Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

```
    org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withNamedScope(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object; at 
    org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtils$.createStream(KinesisUtils.scala:67)
```

Which does include the kinesis ASL jar in the resulting uber jar

```
[INFO] Including org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:jar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:jar:1.3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.9.16 in the shaded jar.
```

Comment: check your java version

Comment: @eliasah could you please be more specific on what you mean by checking the java version?